# Quit vim, when a buffer has unsaved changes and is un-named?

Tags: vim, editor

I created a blank "scratch buffer" (i.e. not associated with a specific file) in vim, by using `:vnew`.  Then I played around with some text, now I simply want to exit the editor - not  keeping the contents of this "scratch buffer".

When I type the command:

```
:q!
```

Vim gives me:

```
[No Name][+]                                               
E37: No write since last change (add ! to  override)  
E162: No write since last change for buffer "[No Name]"  
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I quit vim from this state?

Comment: Can you provide full steps to reproduce this? I’ve tried it myself, and I can use `:q` just fine.

Comment: unfortunately no. but if it works for you , hopefully I have just stumbled across weird - not likely to happen again - case. will try some tests now...

Comment: hmm, when I launch a new instance of vim, `:vnew` , make some edits,  I can quit fine using `:q!`. It may have been some unusual case?

Comment: aha,  I was able to get out of the problematic buffer with `:qa!`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This happens when you have a modified hidden buffer. Use `:qa!` to exit anyway.

From `:h :quit` :

```
:q[uit]!        Quit without writing, also when currently visible
                buffers have changes.  Does not exit when this is the
                last window and there is a changed hidden buffer.
                In this case, the first changed hidden buffer becomes
                the current buffer.
                Use ":qall!" to exit always.
```

---

In case someone wants to reproduce it:

- Start vim and modify the unnamed buffer
- Edit another file (you might need to `:set hidden`), ie `:e README`
- Try to exit with `:q!`

Comment: thanks, yes I believe I must have had a second not hidden, but empty "scratch buffer" open because vim was erroring whilst showing no contents, then when I hit enter to continue, it was restoring contents, I suspect vim was switching to the other buffer?

Answer (score 7):

At best you could call it a "transient" buffer (in memory but not associated with a specific file) but what you created with `:vnew` is *not* a "scratch" buffer.

In Vim, a "scratch" buffer is a normal buffer in which you set a bunch of local options. It can be done with a command like this:

```
:vnew | setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
```