# What is "a modified hidden buffer"? Can I disable this thing?

Tags: vim, editor, buffer

I'm using a portable version of gVim 8.0 and every time I want to start a new "file"\session (I have no idea how should I call it frankly) using `:enew` command or if I want simply to quit the program using `:q (:quit)` I got this error message:

> E37: No write since last change (add ! to override).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935293/how-can-i-quit-vim-when-a-buffer-has-unsaved-changes-and-is-the-buffer-is-un-na) I read that *this happens when you have a modified hidden buffer*. I don't know what that buffer is but I don't like this default behavior. Can I change it somehow so I wouldn't type the question mark every time I need to quit or start anew?

Thank you!

Comment: There are other more approchable editors, you know?

Comment: @romainl of course I know. What is your point?

Comment: You seem to be struggling with Vim so I'd suggest using another editor instead.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set options [`autowrite`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autowrite') and `autowriteall`. They allow to write the contents of the file, if it has been modified, on each :next, :rewind, :last, :first, :previous, :stop, :suspend, :tag, :!, :make, CTRL-] and CTRL-^; `autowriteall` also used for commands ":edit", ":enew", ":quit", ":qall", ":exit", ":xit", ":recover" and closing the Vim window.

```
:set autowrite
:set autowriteall
```

in the current session. Put "set autowrite" and "set autowriteall" in `~/.vimrc` to make this automatic in the future sessions.

If you don't want to automatically write modified buffers but simply switch to another buffer

```
:set hidden
```

(again, both in command line and `~/.vimrc`).

If `autowrite` doesn't work it probably means that the buffer doesn't have a name (isn't associated with a file) — in that case vim cannot write the buffer. `set hidden` helps here but not for `:q`. vim can automatically save files but cannot (and shouldn't) automatically discard changes. You have to discard them explicitly with `:qa!`. This is safety feature.

Comment: thank you very much, but how do I set them, i.e. change their boolean value? I have found them in the help, but it doesn't say how to use them either. I tried "set autowrite" and "set autowriteall" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: `:set autowrite` and `:set autowriteall` in the current session. "set autowrite" and "set autowriteall" in ~/.vimrc to make this automatic in the future sessions. If you don't want to auto write modified buffers but simple switch to another buffer — `:set hidden`; I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: as I said :set autowrite and :set autowriteall (in the current session) didn't change that behavior, exclamation mark was still required. But nevertheless I'll accept your answer because I'm pretty sure there wouldn't be any better. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Might be worth noting that `nohidden` is the default in vim, but `hidden` is the default in neovim. If you migrate to neovim and you want the old behavior back, use `set nohidden` in your `.vimrc` or `vim.opt.hidden = false` in your neovim lua config.